# Unable to read the "../.dev.env" environment file in Dotenv.php:symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want To run a symfony project in my computer but I get all times errors , and now I get this error and i didn't find any solution for my problem

> Problem Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 2: Content is not
> allowed in prolog.. Command C:\xampp\php\php.exe
> C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\bin\console list --format=xml Output
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught
> Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\bin/../.dev.env" environment file. in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php:466 Stack
> trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(51): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array)
>
> ## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\bin\console(38): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
>
> ## 2 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 466

Answer (score 1):

If u move your file from the folder where it was created symfony will keep looking for it on this folder, i've went on autoload_runtime and changed on $runtime variable where the project is, just worked for me, lets see on the last composer dump what just happens haha

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit, do you have a file `C:\xampp\htdocs\buzzaka\bin/../.dev.env` ?

Well, you need to create one. As announced a little while ago, Symfony will now require a .env file per environment. As you are running your command in the dev environment, you need to create a .dev.env file.

Comment: No I don't have dev.env but i have .env